# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net

I have tried to run a solution in VS 2010 which was developed using VS 2008. At that time im receiving the following exception.

Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
 manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Im getting the above exception in the following line of source code

DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

The mentioned solution is working fine in other systems.

I searched and tried to resolve this by deleting all the DLLs from the bin and added the DLLs newly from the c:\ProgramFiles.

But still i am getting the same exception. 
Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Are you adding the correct version?

Comment: Download and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6228

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have a reference to the EnterpriseLibraryData in your config file, with a version. This version is clashing with the latest version expected in VS2010. Check hte config file and the version of the file in your project.